# How to overwrite Ahimsa\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender in M2?

Tags: magento2, order-email

I need to overwrite Ahimsa\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender just to add new methods to return payment informations, but when I put the OrderSender.php file in my custom module do not work.

I Need to overwrite this class to make some changes in new order email template. I do not want to return the payment information like a html block, I need the separate payment information.

Any help?

Tks!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a plugin for it in your custom module. There is a [Magento docs page on it here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html).

It will be something similair to this:

VENDOR/MODULENAME/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="guest-checkout-payment" type="VENDOR\YOURMODULE\Model\Checkout\GuestPaymentInformationManagementPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Replace the path with the path for the php file that you want to write the plugin for. And then create your php file like the doc states.

Comment: In the reading I did in the documentation you can only intercept public methods with the plugin and I need to override a protected method